# sqlsrv and param count error

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, sqlsrv

Good Day,

Before anything else, I can successfully connect to my database and I can
print out all the data from my table..

This is my problem, I am experiencing a *warning and fatal error* when I try to do this:

```
$sql = sqlsrv_query("SELECT [name] FROM [Test].[dbo].[TestTable] WHERE [name] = '$user', $conn);
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($conn,$sql);
```

This is the error that I'm getting,

> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource....Param count and
>   argument count don't match

Answer (score 0):

**Stop concatenating parameters**, it's not safe. Learn about [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Error may be raised because your username parameter contains `?` char.

Also, right [sqlsrv_query syntax](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php) is:

> mixed sqlsrv_query ( resource $conn , string $sql [, array $params [, array $options ]] )

where sql is the **second parameter**, not the first one. Your code should looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT [name] FROM [Test].[dbo].[TestTable] WHERE [name] = ?";
$params = array(1, $user);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, btw, $user = $_POST['Name'], what I am trying to do is, if the Name is correct, it will match it to the database so the user can login.
And yes, I will fix sql injection soon after I can make this simple thing work. :)

Comment: Hmm, I am having log-in errors now, I guess it was working now(not sure)
just to add,
if($stmt ==1){
header("Location: Profile.php";
}else{
Invalid credentials was inserted. }